# vertically positioning content after div transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform, scale

I have content in a div that I am trying to scale according to a user's preferences. I am using [Louis Remi's transform.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js) to do this.

However, when I do, it either:

- Pushes the content way above top of the div (cutting off content on scale in)
- Pushes the content way too far down the container (leaving a lot of white space on scale out)

I've tried to call this snippet on DOM ready

`$("#zoomMe").css({ 'transform' : 'scale(.50)', 'top' : '-2280px' });`

but this only works at specific heights. I was wondering if there was anyway that I can push content to the top of the div even if my container changes heights.

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7VTrL/1/). Right now it is at a .50 scale which shows content being in the middle of the screen leaving a lot of space on top of and bottom of div.

Here is a [detailed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb4vC.png) of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Here is a detailed picture of what I am trying to achieve]

**HTML**

```
<div id="reportContainer">
    <div id="zoomMe">
        <div id="content1" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content2" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content3" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content4" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="content5" class="fillerBox">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#reportContainer { margin: 0;padding:15px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden; border:2px solid black;}
.fillerBox { background-color:#ccc;border:1px dashed #000;height:1500px;width:910px;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:30px; }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reportContainer").height($(window).height()-50);
    $("#zoomMe").css('transform', 'scale(.50)' );
});
```

Comment: so you want to `scale(.50)` and not have content stick to the top?

Comment: @Fresheyeball I've updated the question with a detailed image of what I am looking to achieve. I do want content to stick to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `transform-origin`

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/

This will enable you to set the point on your element that will stay put as transforms occur. By setting the `transform-origin` to the top center: you can scale the element and keep its position relative to the top in the same place.

Comment: CSS3 transforms are my jam yo.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me! I don't know much about this transform.js plugin, but the property you want to look at is "transform-origin". Your issue is that it's scaling #zoomMe from the center, making your post-transform content 25% offset from the top and bottom.

**CSS**

```
#zoomMe {
 transform-origin:center top;
 -webkit-transform-origin:center top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Taylor! The help is appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize someone else had commented!! It was unanswered when I started, I promise :) thank you for the +1 Bryan!